# Stack Overflow Worldwide Meetups 2012

Tags: discussion, meetups, events

We [recently announced](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/) the Second Annual Stack Overflow Meetup Everywhere day. This year, it will be on Saturday, April 28 (though local groups are welcome to pick any other day that week if a Saturday doesn't work for most of your members).

**What:** Stack Overflow worldwide meetups

**When:** Saturday, April 28, 2012

**Where:** your city!

**Who:** All Stack Overflow users and the greater Stack Exchange tech community

You can visit the [official Meetup.com page](http://www.meetup.com/stackoverflow/) to find existing groups near you (or start a new one). Keep an eye on the Stack Exchange blog for more information as we move closer to the event - I'll post tips on what we learned from last year's event and some things to keep in mind when organizing your local meetup. See the [blog announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/) for some ideas about what your meetup can look like, why we're doing this, and some help navigating the meetup.com interface.

We'd love to see as many of you as possible participate in our Meetup Everywhere. We had over 2,000 people meet up around the world last year, and we've grown a lot since then. Help us spread the word by sharing info about this event through your blogs, social media accounts, lunches with coworkers, etc.

As always, if you have any questions or comments, do not hesitate to get in touch!

Comment: my big question is ... why did we choose Saturday ? For the Sydney one we are pushing it to Monday

Comment: @waffles Alison and Rebecca, who planned last year's event, told me that they received a bunch of feedback from people who thought weekdays didn't work well for a variety of reasons (working late, finding babysitters, nearest meetup location being a long drive away, etc.). So we're trying a weekend day this year. Next year, we'll have both weekday and weekend to compare and can use these experiences to inform our planning. I'm happy the Sydney group is choosing a day that works for them, though - that's great!

Comment: And in post-meetup news: Three people showed up at the Amsterdam meet, and *all three* seem to have missed each other by minutes.

Comment: The official meetup.com page returns "The Meetup Group you're looking for doesn't exist"

Answer (score 4):

I'm hosting the London 2012 meetup day.  I just got the box O' Swag (thank you!!!) I'm putting together events for the day, I've got some people willing to give talks.  I'm going to put up times for lighting talks and we'll have a Kinect (with the new Star Wars game!) setup.

What are other folks doing for their meetups?  I'd love more good ideas!

Comment: Wishing **we** had an organized organizer ;)

Comment: Catch a flight up to London and come to ours!!!

Comment: Why don't you catch a flight to Israel and organize ours ;)

Comment: That would be kind of awesome, but I'm not sure I could get work to sponsor it, also, I'm busy organizing the London one!

Comment: Oh well.. can't say I didn't try :)  Good luck! Hope it doesn't rain ;)

Comment: It's London, of *course* it will rain.