# University Ambassadors for SE community promotion

Tags: discussion, community, site-promotion, events

Recently, I stumbled upon this old post (2011) on Quantitative Finance SE: [Quant.SE University Ambassadors Program: calling students and teachers](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/q/240), which announced an (private?) initiative to run a "meet your community at the Universities and promote SE community there".

I was not able to find anything similar on Meta SE, so I wonder if

- we have something similar to that active
- we had successful/unsuccessful past experiments
- it is even possible to organize something like that, maybe starting very local and small-scale

In particular, I am very interested in such opportunities to promote [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) community. A large portion of our audience is in the universities (senior undergraduates, graduates, postdocs, research staff, and, of course, professors).

Comment: Most related is this one: [Stack Overflow Worldwide Meetups 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128183/stack-overflow-worldwide-meetups-2012) (TL;DR: in the past there used to be such events, but not for long years due to lack of interest and active participants.)

Comment: Quite related: [Announcing the Stack Overflow Student Ambassador Program](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381614/335251)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we have something similar to that active

Yes. During 2022, Student Ambassador Program was launched.

More details here: [Announcing the Stack Overflow Student Ambassador Program](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381614/announcing-the-stack-overflow-student-ambassador-program?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 11):

There have been several opportunities for these kinds of initiatives to come to life.  For example, our International Stack Overflow communities have hosted several meetups most of which have been community organized and led.  I would be very interested in hearing about what ideas you have and also how we can support you to in helping other members and potential newcomers meet face to face to promote your community.

Here is an example of a conversation we had over at [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1371/objetivos-2017-encuentros-locales) about this very thing.

Comment: Juan, [this was](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4090/324) the last one in bogota, colombia.

Answer (score 4):

When I was more active at Wikipedia, I used to attend the [Pittsburgh meetup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Meetup/Pittsburgh) fairly regularly, looks like it has not been active recently.

Wikipedia is has a fairly organized approach [Wikipedia:Meetup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Meetup) that is successful in many areas. I don't see any reason why it could not work as well for a SE site.  In my experience at Wikipedia, if you have someone (i.e. you) in an area who wants to do the work of organizing, and if you have a couple of people who will attend regularly, others will stop by to check it out.

On an SE site you could use a combination of meta post and an event chat room to bring it all together.

If you want to try it, go for it.

Comment: Travel Stack Exchange [also has an active meetup culture](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/where-can-one-meet-other-travel-se-members).

Answer (score 0):

We have had various meetups and competitions on security Stack Exchange, and back in its early days, I did an outreach visit to San Francisco security conferences to raise awareness.

I try to take SE swag to all the conferences I host or volunteer at, and even if I don't, I wear a Sec.SE t-shirt and encourage both asking if questions and general chat.

For conferences with students, especially if I'm lecturing, I try to point students at SE questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an [old (2011) post in StackOverflow blog on Supporting Community Conferences](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/04/supporting-community-conferences/) that talks about various ways SE team can help in promoting on conferences, seminars, conventions, events, meetups by providing:

- flyers
- StackExchange swag from the [Store](http://store.stackexchange.com/) that no longer exist. Also, it would be of little value for a community in Beta state as is [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)
- business cards
- event sponsorship/fees underwriting
- sponsoring community leaders to attend/speak

These are the support that might have been available for certain situations back in 2011. I am not aware what/if any of that is still in action.